# Google font Rubik not working or am I missing something?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm using Google's font Rubik on a website (still work in progress) and it stopped showing any text suddenly!

It seems that even on Google Font website the font isn't working:
https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Rubik:400,900&query=rubik
("All their equipment and instruments are alive." isn't showing below Rubik, but if you inspect it, it is in there)

Is anyone else having the same problem?

I'm having this issue using Windows and Chrome, Firefox or Edge.

UPDATE: without changing anything, the font started working again today. I guess whatever problem existed, Google fixed it.

Comment: Looks fine here. Does it work in another browser? Is this maybe the result of an attempt to install Rubik locally?

Comment: No, I have the same issue on Firefox and Edge when I open the link https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Rubik:400,900&query=rubik

Comment: Font seems to work fine (see [codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/KvyrKo)).

Comment: No. I can't see it in codepen either. Where are you guys connecting from? I'm in the UK and this issue seems to be happening here. A guy from Australia confirmed he can see the font.

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Could you just clean up your cache and run it again.

Comment: Yep. I did that already. Still nothing. Not even showing up in incognito mode

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem, only in Windows, though. MacOS works. Also tried IE and Chrome. Both don't show the font.

Comment: Same problem for me. I suggest you use the Feedback option on their website to report it. As my website is in production I switched to Roboto.

Comment: I can confirm that is seems to work again. :)

Comment: Please accept the answer so that the question doesn't show up on the unanswered list dude. The button is under the voting widget.

Answer (score 2):

Upon further investigation, it seems their font for "Rubik" is corrupt or otherwise problematic. Conversion to `ttf` gives the same results. The font can be previewed under Windows, but the behavior in-browser (FF56.0b2) is the same.

Browsers that appear to render it might be doing what mine was, using a system fallback that looks similar.

This is an issue on their end as the problem is with the font file and not their stylesheet as I had originally stated in this answer.

I converted the `woff` to `ttf` using Google's [woff2 tool](https://github.com/google/woff2), then tried the `ttf` version locally, without `unicode-range` and the results are the same. Here is a preview of the `truetype` version of the font, converted from the `woff2` version, in FontForge, if anyone wants to see if the glyph's are in the correct location (note that this version of the font *also doesn't work in-browser*):

[image: ![truetype font glyphs](http://imgur.com/a/Ztx7c)]

Answer (score 2):

Google Fonts pushed an update with hinting that had a bug for some rendering systems, and rolled back the update within 24 hours.

Comment: Corroboration: https://twitter.com/googlefonts/status/899838144236990464

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the "/" after ".com" and add a space it worked for me.  This font was working for me yesterday, so now the only problem is if they fix the path it wont work again.  Hope this helps