# Google font disappearing from all browsers on specific website

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

This morning the Google font implementation of "Rubik" sans on my web app mysteriously disappeared from all browsers, i.e. anytime I load the site all the text is missing. Initially I thought it was restricted to Chrome later found out it applied to all the browsers. Tried clearing cache, tried restarting the system Same problem. This is indeed very weird, never experienced anything like this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709441/google-font-rubik-not-working-or-am-i-missing-something) asked 4 hours ago, I think it was a google side error.
on my side it seem [repaired](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Rubik:400,900&query=rubik) [2](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rubik?selection.family=Rubik:400,900), if it persists, try reloading your cache

Comment: Still the same after 11 hours. Doesn't load anywhere. Funny thing is some other PCs and mobile devices load the font perfectly. Currently it appears like it is only mine that is affected.

Comment: Eventually had to host the font file myself on the server. Worked after that. The one being served from Google was probably corrupt.